# PHP array to string with newline characters

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I'd like to convert an array to string with newline characters for simplest text formatting. The array is a result of a mysql select query and I suppose I need a loop which uses the implode function to convert to string and separate the fields with something (i.e. " * ") and at the end of each row ads a newline character.

sample output

```
  2018-06-22 * meeting * They didn't want to buy anythin
  2018-06-23 * * called and wanted to buy something
  2018-06-24 * meeting * Gave specification
```

I was thinking something like this (but I am wrong and this is why I ask):

```
      $Diary =''; // start with empty string
      $array = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch);// fetched already
      $length = count($array);

      for ($x = 0; $length; $x++ + 3) {
      $temparray = // use a temp array for one row only
      $Diary = // increment a string until the end of the row, add newline at the end
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code of what you have tried to solve this?

Comment: can you show the sample output ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Do you have an example input?  What code have you tried so far?

Comment: `convert an array to string with newline characters` : an example? `result of a mysql select query` : please show us the query + result. `I suppose I need a loop which uses the implode function (...)` : show us what you try ? And what doesn't work btw, I saw no error?

Answer (score -1):

And here's the answer. "Thanks" for all the downvoting.

```
  $Diary ='';   
  $query  = 'SELECT tb2_date, tb2_note, tb2_entry from DiaryTable WHERE tb2_tb1ID = 
  "'.$HiddenID.'" ORDER BY tb2_date DESC';
  $resulto = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_row($resulto)) {
    $rowimploded = implode(' ** ', $rows);  
    $newline = "\r\n";
    $Diary = $Diary.$rowimploded.$newline;      
}
mysqli_free_result($resulto);

// echo $Diary or whatever...
```